# What are considered excessive rollover IRA administrative fees?

Tags: united-states, ira, fees, rollover

My husband has a rollover IRA and is being charged annual administrative fees of 1.94%. Is this too much?

Comment: Fidelity and Vanguard have 0% fees.  What are you getting for the 1.94%?

Comment: Think about 1.94% in terms of how much of the gain in the IRA is being lost just to fees.  If the return it provides is 6% (as an example), that means you're giving up almost a third of your gains for essentially nothing.    I'd search for a different manager, such as Fidelity or Vanguard, as @Pete suggests.  Not all of them charge fees.

Comment: what type of funds is the IRA invested in? Active? Index? sector?...

Comment: 1.94% should be criminal.

Comment: ? No idea what this means. $70,000 that is proposed to be put in a multiple strategy ACCount, Profile 3, Moderate. If we do not make a move we will run out of retirement income. 60% in Core Markets, 40% in Diversifying strategies-Bonds and bond alternative.  WE put our faith in Invest Financial Corportation, Syracuse, NY and thought they were looking out for us.

Answer (score 2):

I found a large US company that provides this service that has a $20 annual fee, but only if the account is less that $10,000. Above that there is no fee. There are other large asset managers that have similar fee structures. A 1.94% fee is borderline criminal in my estimation.

(Company not named so an not to be an ad.)